# Elasticsearch 6.2.4 [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9)"}]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, querydsl

I am using Elasticsearch 6.2.4 with my RoR application using elasticsearch-rails and elasticsearch-model.

My indexation is runninng without getting any errors. but when I try to perform a search from the application I am getting this error from Elasticsearch

```
<Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9)"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9)"},"status":400}>
```

Everything was working normal prior to the upgrade of Elasticsearch from 1.5 to 6.2.4

I simplified my search query to try narrowing down the problem.

```
q = { "query" => { "match_all" => {} } }
```

But I still getting the same error. Probably I am not specifying a type in the query but wouldn't be unnecessary since I have a match_all condition ?

```
> {"query":{"match_all":{}}}
< {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9)"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9)"},"status":400}
```

I am brand new to Elasticsearch so excuse me in advance if there are some evident stuff that I am missing

Do you have any idea what is causing this error ? If you need more specific info just ask and I'll update this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Search request from application is resulting in HTTP 400 Bad Request. Are you able to perform a search request from outside the application i.e. invoking a curl command from your local etc ?